# ng2-bootstrap accordion how to create interactive dropdown arrow

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, ng2-bootstrap

I have the following accordion:

[image]

**I need arrow to be like this `^` when accordion open and like this `v` when accordion closed**

The markup looks like this, notice `(click)="toggleAssignedTasks()"` on `div`accordion-heading with this I toggleAssignedTasks and then I change the class of the fontawesome down arrow to up or up accordingly:

```
 <accordion class="row th-assigned-ready">
        <accordion-group [isOpen]="isAssignedTasksVisible" >
            <div class="th-heading" accordion-heading (click)="toggleAssignedTasks()">
                <strong class="th-text-ready">Ready for Review (2)</strong>
                <i class="fa"
                   [ngClass]="{'fa-chevron-down': isAssignedTasksVisible, 'fa-chevron-up': !isAssignedTasksVisible}"
                   aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
             ... 
            </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
```

This is working but when user clicks in accordion the event gets messed up it seems the (click) event is being absorbed by the accordions default event.

I also tried using native [showArrows]="true" in the accordion like this:

but I get error:

```
Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'showArrows' since it isn't a known native property ("
            </div>

            <accordion class="row th-assigned-ready" [ERROR ->][showArrows]="true" >
                <accordion-group [isOpen]="isAssignedTasksVisible" >
        "):
```

## UPDATE:

toggleAssignedTasks() looks like this

```
public toggleAssignedTasks(): void {
    this.isAssignedTasksVisible = (this.isAssignedTasksVisible) ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `toggleAssignedTasks()` function? Also, why are you using an italics tag for the chevron? Finally, `showArrows` isn't native so Angular is looking for a property on the Accordian component that doesn't exist thus the error. If possible, try to reproduce the effect you're seeing in a plunker and it will be much easier for someone to help you figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @AndrewBabin posted update thank you

Comment: Can you help better understand what exactly is going wrong? For one thing, in `[ngClass]="{'fa-chevron-down': isAssignedTasksVisible, 'fa-chevron-up': !isAssignedTasksVisible}"
                   aria-hidden="true">`, you have the down chevron class applied when `isAssignedTasksVisible` is true and the up chevron applied when it is false. This would give you the opposite of what you are looking for (you want the ^ when the tasks are visible). This may throw off `toggleAssignedTasks()` if `isAssignedTasksVisible` has a default value.

Comment: @AndrewBabin, thanks. Well what is happening now is that accordion is closing even when I click on any item in the accordian which is not what I want. I only want it to open or close on click of chevron element.

Comment: @AndrewBabin do you know how to stop event that closes accordion when I click on accordion header. the grey part that says "Ready for reviews(2)" in my posted image

Comment: Put the `(click)="toggleAssignedTasks()"` on the tag for the chevron element and that should give you what you are looking for.  The `(click)` attaches a click event listener to whatever element you put it on. Right now you have it on the div for the entire heading.

Comment: @AndrewBabin thanks for your help the problem was that clicking on any part of accordion group closed it Im posting my solution anyways thanks for your help!!! have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that my accordion was being closed on click of accordion group so I solved it by doing this:

```
       <accordion class="row th-assigned-ready" >
            <accordion-group [isOpen]="isAssignedTasksVisible" (click)="onAssignedReadyClick()">
                <div class="th-heading" accordion-heading>
                    <strong class="th-text-ready">Ready for Review (2)</strong>
                    <i class="fa"
                       [ngClass]="{'fa-chevron-down': isAssignedTasksVisible, 'fa-chevron-up': !isAssignedTasksVisible}"
                       aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <ul (click)="stopAccordionClose($event); false">
                  //NOTICE stopAccordionClose
                </ul>
            </accordion-group>
        </accordion>
```

and this is how my component.ts looks:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "task",
    templateUrl: "task.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["task.scss"],
    directives: [
        HeaderInternalComponent,
        ACCORDION_DIRECTIVES,
    ],
})

export class TaskComponent extends MeteorComponent implements OnInit {

    //more code...


    public toggleAssignedTasks(): void {
        this.isAssignedTasksVisible = (this.isAssignedTasksVisible) ? false : true;
    }

    public toggleAssignedNotComplete(): void {
        this.isAssignedNotCompleteVisible = (this.isAssignedNotCompleteVisible) ? false : true;
    }

    public onAssignedReadyClick(): boolean {
        this.toggleAssignedTasks();
        return false;
    }

    public onAssignedNotCompleteClick(): boolean {
        this.toggleAssignedNotComplete();
        return false;
    }

    public stopAccordionClose($event): boolean {
        $event.stopPropagation()
        $event.preventDefault()
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the standard `group?.isOpen` method, like described [here](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/index-bs4.html#/accordion):