# What does the <i> tag mean in this angular bootstrap example?

Tags: angular

I was looking through another stackoverflow post when I noticed some syntax I was not familiar with and could not google the answers to. Can anyone point me to some documentation for how the `<i>` tag is used here and what is it called? "Interactive"? I have only ever known `<i>` to mean italics, which is not what's happening here.

```
<accordion class="row th-assigned-ready">
    <accordion-group [isOpen]="isAssignedTasksVisible" >
        <div class="th-heading" accordion-heading (click)="toggleAssignedTasks()">
            <strong class="th-text-ready">Ready for Review (2)</strong>
            <i class="fa"
                   [ngClass]="{'fa-chevron-down': isAssignedTasksVisible, 'fa-chevron-up': !isAssignedTasksVisible}"
                   aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        ... 
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Here is the original post: [ng2-bootstrap accordion how to create interactive dropdown arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985802/ng2-bootstrap-accordion-how-to-create-interactive-dropdown-arrow)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use <i> tag for icons instead of <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span)

Comment: @AlanYu While that question answers the "why", it doesn't answer the "what". The question is "What does `<i>` mean in this example?" instead of "Should I use `<i>` or `<span>`?". It might help a tiny bit, but it nowhere close to being enough to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*< i >* was the tag for italics, but nowadays, in the way you're using it (with *class="fa ..."*, is used for **Icons**.

There're several ways to use it, but when you see somehing like
`<i class="fa ..."` *fa* stands for **FontAwesome**.

FontAwesome is a famous gallery of icons (and other graphics)
*Here you have access to the free galery*:
https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2&m=free

In order to use some icon, you only have to get its name.
For instance, the second icon of that list, the icon of accesibility, you would use it in that way:

```
<i class="fa fa-accessible-icon"></i>
```

You only have to click in the icon you like, and it opens a page when the web itself shows the exact way to use the icon (in the way as I show you above), along with other ways to use it (filled, flat, larger, etc).

EXTRA: **Dynamic selection of the icon with ngClass**

In your example, beside the i for icon, has the peculiarity that the second parameter that i needs, *is being set dynamically with [ngClass]*.

For instance, whereas a 'regular' icon is in that way:

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
```

Your code is putting actually all these icons:

```
<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> // If the isAssignedTasksVisible variable is true
<i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> // If the isAssignedTasksVisible variable is false
```

It does so thanks to **[ngClass]**, in this part of the code:

```
[ngClass]="{'fa-chevron-down': isAssignedTasksVisible, 'fa-chevron-up': !isAssignedTasksVisible}
```

NOTE: Hi folks! I see in the comments that it creates controversy xD, but I'm just saying how it's used nowadays by most developers on the front end, **please, don't kill the messenger! xD**
So that if you see it in the code, you know what it is being used for and you don't have the doubt that the OP **@wheeeee** had, which is precisely a very common doubt because of the "double use" that is given to that <i tag and that you are emphasising in the comments. Have nice and see you around!

Comment: `<i>` is an HTML tag for idiomatic / italic: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_i.asp.
HTML does not define any tag for icons. It's just a specific CSS library that styles it as an icon. Otherwise is you answer correct

Comment: `< i > is the tag for Icons.` <-- No, it's not... It's the Idiomatic Text element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i), often styled as italic text. It is used for icons because it starts with the same letter as the word "icon". Pure coincidence.

Comment: (Saids for @SLaks user) The <i> tag is discouraged, because it provides no semantic indication about why the text is italic.
To display italic text, the <em> tag should be used. (or a different tag with appropriate semantic meaning, combined with CSS)
**More recently, people have started using <i> tags for icons, because i stands for icon.**

Comment: @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero That's not true. Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i. It makes no sense to use `<em>` for, for example, text in other language within your text. Meanwhile, using `<i>` is the best fit for those.

Comment: From https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_intro.asp: " The <i> and <span> elements are widely used for icons.".... I'm not telling that <i> html was not used for italics, I say that, nowadays, frontenders to make italis usually use <em> or a custom css class, and the major use of <i> is for icons.

Comment: @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero So? Just because they are widely used for that doesn't mean it is what they represent. I can also use a table to make a layout on a website. Does it make sense? No! Was it used a lot? Yes! Should I use it? No! NO NO NO! Except for emails... The `<i>` tag is popularly used for icons, but doesn't mean it is an icon. It has a semantic meaning in HTML, different from `<em>`, despite being stylized the same. But doesn't mean you can swap both. It's just a bad practice we accepted today, like how we accepted tables for layouts back when...